# SQL Script reference to Excel Cells

Tags: sql, excel, vba

```
Sub SQL()
'Clearing the existing cells
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Sheet1.Range("A1:D10000").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Clear
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

'Setting up the connection
Dim sSQLQry As String
Dim ReturnArray
Dim Conn As New ADODB.Connection
Dim m As New ADODB.Recordset
Dim DBPath As String, sconnect As String

sconnect = "Provider=SQLOLEDB; Data Source=backoffice.db.mid.dom,4161; Initial Catalog=BackOffice; Integrated Security=SSPI;"

Conn.Open sconnect

"'SQL Script
'DB1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Import to SQL").Range(c2").Value
    sSQLString = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Scripts").Range("C2:C3").Value
    m.Open sSQLString, Conn

'Paste Date and Close Connection
    Sheet1.Range("A21").CopyFromRecordset m
    m.Close

'Set/name the column header
Sheet1.Cells(20, 1) = "ProductCode"
Sheet1.Cells(20, 2) = "Nr of Trades"
Sheet1.Cells(20, 3) = "Trade_date"
Sheet1.Cells(20, 4) = "Date_Retrieved"

Conn.Close

End Sub
```

Hi All,
Having a problem with the SQL script that is currently placed in 1 cell (C2). What I want to do is to spread the script in order to have 1 cell for each line of script.
When I split the script into 2 cells and it is in C2 and C3 the VBA gives an error 3001.

```
C2 ="Select ProductCode, FORMAT(count(distinct(tradeid)),'#,#') as Nr_Trades, TradeDate, GETDATE() From BackOffice.dbo.trades
where 1 = 1 
and TradeDate ="&E2&"group by ProductCode, TradeDate"
C3 ="order by count(distinct(tradeid)) asc"
```

Comment: In `sSQLString =` just concatenate the two cells with `&`

Comment: Do you mean like: sSQLString = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Scripts").Range("C2&C3").Value?   It still cannot understand it is split - same error